# Racket random function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having trouble with the random function. I have a function set up where:

```
(define random-abcd
  (cond [(equal? (random 4) 0) 'A]
        [(equal? (random 4) 1) 'B]
        [(equal? (random 4) 2) 'C]
        [else 'D]
        ))
```

However when I run this 'D comes out substantially more often than any of the other choices. It seems like whatever is in the code for [else ...] happens much more than the other choices meaning that it's not choosing  with equal probability. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `random` function works fine, but your code is wrong. You want this instead:

```
(define random-abcd
  (let ([n (random 4)])
    (cond [(equal? n 0) 'A]
          [(equal? n 1) 'B]
          [(equal? n 2) 'C]
          [else 'D])))
```

In your original example, you generated a new random number for every comparison. This *seems* like it shouldn't affect the distribution, but it does.

In your original formulation, the second case required that the first case was false *and* the second case was true, giving an actual probability of `3/4 * 1/4`, or `3/16`. The third case had a probability of `13/16 * 1/4`, or `13/64`. All cases should have a probability of `1/4` for an equal distribution, and this error skewed your entire set of values.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the let function since I'm stuck in beginning student language?

Comment: @Ryan You could do it with `define`. Just do `(define n (random 4))` just above the `random-abcd` definition.

Comment: Hmm.. That does works for one output. I have this function linked to a recursive function that creates a list of cons. The code for that part of it is: (cons  random-abcd (cons random-abcd empty)) But now it doesn't run a new random function it just runs it once and uses that choice for the entire list. How would I fix that?

Comment: @Ryan Make `random-abc` a function. So do `(define (random-abc) (define n (random 4)) ...)`.

Comment: You can't define a function inside another function, so that wouldn't work though

Comment: @Ryan I don't know about in BSL, but in Racket you can.

Comment: @Ryan, you want to define a helper function that does the conditional, and then call it with the appropriate random number.